# DISTRO 'stretch' not found

Tags: build, debian, yocto

I am trying to use Yocto and nneta-elbe to build a debian based custom linux image.

I have used the commands given in https://elbe-rfs.org/download/ followed by README to set up nneta-elbe, but when I run bitbake hello I run into this issue.

I am running Yocto on a Debian 11.

> ERROR: OE-core's config sanity checker detected a potential
> misconfiguration. Either fix the cause of this error or at your own
> risk disable the checker (see sanity.conf). Following is the list of
> potential problems / advisories: DISTRO 'stretch' not found. Please
> set a valid DISTRO in your local.conf MACHINE=mymachine is invalid.
> Please set a valid MACHINE in your local.conf, environment or other
> configuration file.

My nneta-elbe folder is inside my poky folder

I have not altered the local.conf file however have added my own bblayers.conf as it is not given in the repo's sample conf

This is what my bblayers.conf file looks like:

> POKY_BBLAYERS_CONF_VERSION = "2"
> BBPATH = "${TOPDIR}"
> BBFILES ?= ""
> BBLAYERS ?= " /home/yocto/Projects/yocto/poky/nneta-elbe "

Can someone guide me or help me fix the distro issue?

Comment: »» I have used the commands «« : Your commands are missing! I guess you used the "Stretch commands"? . ............... You are supposed to use the commands for "buster or later" : Debian 10 is buster. Debian 11 is bullseye.

Comment: I did use the buster or later commands. Within the repo there are distributions, as a reference to which distro of linux to build the custom image on. This error is something to do with that